# How to remove .DS_Store from command-line auto-completion using cd?

Tags: terminal, macos, auto-complete

I understand that `.DS_store` files serve a purpose. That said, they are a nuisance when auto-completing with the `cd` command. When I type `cd` in Terminal and press tab twice it lists all directories in the working directory.

**Is there a way of removing `.DS_store` from this auto-complete directory listing in the terminal?**

Comment: When I type `cd` in Terminal then key Tab twice: there's a prompt before all possibilities (not only directories) are listed.

Comment: That's seems like better behaviour; Do you know how to prevent listing of files when double tabbing after cd?

Comment: `cd */` followed by two tabs lists all subdirectories of the current directory. But you have to backspace to select one...

Comment: @lhf Thanks. It's good to have that option. It would be better if `cd` was smart enough to only list directories by default.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`export FIGNORE=DS_Store` works for me.

The [GNU Bash manual provides extensive information on programmable completion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html).

Specifically, from the [documentation on bash variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables)

> FIGNORE [is a] colon-separated list of suffixes to ignore when performing
>   filename completion. A file name whose suffix matches one of the
>   entries in FIGNORE is excluded from the list of matched file names. A
>   sample value is ‘.o:~’

If you are concerned that there might be existing suffixes in `FIGNORE`, then you can use:

```
export FIGNORE=$FIGNORE:DS_Store
```

Comment: Not sure about you, but it had to be `$FIGNORE:.DS_Store` on mac for me. Didn't work without the "."

Comment: @typeoneerror, same for me. Perhaps in the past it worked as posted. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: In macOS Sierra 10.12.5, it works for me only if I omit the `.`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're really looking for is context-aware tab completion for Bash commands.  For example, `.DS_Store` is a regular file, not a directory, so it should not show up as a possible completion to `cd`.

The package that solves this problem is called `bash-completion`.  I use Fink's version (`fink install bash-completion`), and it's also available from MacPorts (`port install bash-completion`) and Homebrew (`brew install bash-completion`).

After the package is installed and configured in your .bashrc or .bash_profile, regular files will no longer show up as completions for cd, and many other common bash commands become context aware as well (eg. `gunzip`).

Answer (score 1):

While you're asking about only .DS_Store I think removing all hidden files from autocomplete will be better in general. This can be done by the command:

> bind 'set match-hidden-files off'

you can add it ~/.bash_profile to have it invoked every time for you. This will not disable autocompletion for hidden files completely, you still can type '.' (dot) and hit tab for it.

Answer (score -1):

I would use this command:

```
zip -r foo.zip foo -x "*.DS_Store"
```

<sup>Found here:
https://superuser.com/questions/198569/compressing-folders-on-a-mac-without-the-ds-store</sup>

Comment: How does this solve the problem of removing .DS_Store from autocomplete?

Comment: Well, actually it does not. But I stumbled upon that page while searching for "mac zip without .DS_STORE". So I thought that maybe it could help someone else. It's probably a bad idea though.